# How to make Haxe communicate with Java(Processing 2) / Arduino?

Tags: java, arduino, processing, haxe, serial-communication

I'm currently using Haxe with Flash target for a project.
What I want to do is to send a serial signal to my Arduino board, I couldn't find a way using only Haxe so I'm using Processing 2(http://processing.org/) which gets the job done.
The problem now is to make Haxe and Processing communicate, I've tried looking into memory mapped files, but Haxe and Java seem to work differently with those (Haxe needs an Int for address and Java uses a file).
And even creating a file to be read by processing and written by Haxe isn't working (Java gives a FileNotFound execption).

The main goal is to make Haxe send a signal to Arduino, I'm just using Processing 2 as a bridge, but any solution is welcome.

Do any one know a good way to solve this problem?
Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) to communicate between software. Typically they are used over the internet, but it works great locally as well. For Processing, you would use the [Network](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/index.html) library, and it appears Haxe [has a library](http://haxe.org/api/sys/net/socket) as well.